# using the result of current query as a field of itself

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

Essentially, I would like to query a table based on the result of itself to use as part of its Select statement

```
select error_log.err_rfp_num                                                                as task_id,
   error_log.descr                                                                          as task_desc,
   error_log.user_id                                                                        as entered_by,
   error_log.ctrl_date || ' ' || error_log.ctrl_time    as entered_datetime,
   error_log.task_type_cd,
   task_type.descr                                      as task_type_desc,
   client.client_num                                    as client_cd,
   client.descr                                                                                 as client_name,
   error_log.reported_by,
   product.descr                                                                                as product_name,
   product_ver.descr                                                                        as product_version,
   error_log.module_cd,
   error_log.proj_cd                                                                        as parent_task_id,
   (
      select error_log.descr 
      from error_log
      where error_log.err_rfp_num = error_log.proj_cd
   )                                                    as parent_task_desc,
     error_log.task_status
    FROM error_log
    inner   join client
     on (client.client_num = error_log.client_num)
    inner   join product
     on (product.product_num = error_log.product_num)
    inner join task_type
     on error_log.task_type_cd = task_type.task_type_cd
    inner    join product_ver
     on (product_ver.version_num = error_log.version_num AND product_ver.product_num = error_log.product_num)
    left outer join error_status
     on error_status.status_num = error_log.task_status
    and error_status.product_num = 74
    where error_log.task_status in ('1', '2', '3')
```

parent_task_desc (error_log.proj_cd) is simply a description of error_log.err_rfp_num.

The parent tasks and subtasks are all in one table

How can I setup my select statement to use the result of the query within the query itself?

Comment: your select is valid until it returns single row, cant you self join ur table?

Comment: I suspect that you want a recursive CTE, but it is hard to tell how to write one based on this query.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, I am not familiar with Self Joins, I will look it up.

Comment: Just another inner join with error_log second time with different alias joing the erro_cd of first table with rfp num of second.. so you can refer second table's descr in select, without a subquery.. Still you may get a better versions!

Comment: Thanks @MaheswaranRavisankar! I did what you said (changing it to Left Outer join since i want all records) and it worked great! thanks again